# Tomcat 7: avoid automatic restart when change context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat

When I edit the global `conf/context.xml` of my Tomcat 7.0.34 the server seems to restart automatically. I want to avoid the AUTOMATIC restart, the server should run with the "old" configuration until I restart it by hand.

So my question is: **How to avoid the AUTOMATIC restart when I change the global `conf/context.xml` in Tomcat 7.0.34?**

Comment: have you tried setting `autodeploy=false` in the `host` attribute of the `server.xml` file?

Comment: @epoch: not yet, it is still `autodeploy=true` because I expected that this effects only the application but not the global config files.

Comment: Are you running this tomcat from an IDE? As a service ? What is your OS?

Comment: @subirkumarsao: I am not running it from an IDE, OS: Linux

Comment: @EJP: why is this question of topic? It is a question that is not specific for me (7 upvotes), and there is even a "Tomcat" tag in SO, so what is the reason for "of topic"? -- I do not want to complain, I only want to understand it?

Comment: I second that. This post should not be closed, it is of value and very much "on topic"

Comment: Why is this question cloesd because of topic? -- The (even in "closed of topic" linked) scope definition say: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers: ... **software tools commonly used by programmers**" -- I am pretty sure that "Tomcat" is a tool commonly used by java web developers. -- So please reopen the question or expain what is wrong and what should I do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Automatic Application Deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic%20Application%20Deployment), the application will be redeployed when changes are detected

> Updating a context file will trigger an undeploy of the application with the removal of any associated work directory. Any current user sessions will not be persisted. The application will be redeployed the next time the auto deployer checks for changes.

To stop this functionality the `autodeploy` flag must be set to `false`:

> This flag value indicates if Tomcat should check periodically for new or updated web applications while Tomcat is running. If true, Tomcat periodically checks the appBase and $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine_name]/[host_name] directories and deploys any new web applications or context XML descriptors found.

Alternatively, you can set the `deployIgnore` flag with a regular expression defining which applications should be ignored from automatic deployment

Comment: `autodeploy=false` seams also to disable the periodically checks of `$CATALINA_BASE/conf` (not only the sub directories `/[engine_name]/[host_name]`) -- so `autodeploy=false` seams to be the right answer.

Comment: If you set `autodeploy=false` in server.xml then you need to restart the tomcat7 service to take effect.