# How and when to clean and restart while editing code on tomcat production server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

This question is going to consist many subquestions.

1. in eclipse I clean the project after making changes in .java or .xml files.How can I clean it using command line?
2. What exactly clean and build does? cleaning is same as that of restarting  a server?
3. What scenarios(developer point of view) requires Server restart?
4. editing css, html doesn't require server restart.On what file edits I should restart the server?
5. Server.xml and context.xml requires restart or not?

Comment: Clean basically means delete class files. A Clean All will delete all class files from all packages in the current project. The build will then simply compile all java files, which creates all the class files again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in eclipse I clean the project after making changes in .java or .xml
>   files.How can I clean it using command line?

You can run javac from command line, but its not going to be very convenient. Recommend using a build tool like maven (or at least ant) for building your project. These tools can be run from command line and create your war

> What exactly clean and build does? cleaning is same as that of
>   restarting a server?

Clean deletes the classes folder and build compiles your source code and creates the classes folder and the .class files

> What scenarios(developer point of view) requires Server restart?

You can use tomcat manager to hot-deploy your war so a server restart is not required - however you probably should not be doing this in production.

> editing css, html doesn't require server restart.On what file edits I
>   should restart the server?

Any changes to java files (deployed in WEB-INF/classes) or jars (in WEB-INF/lib) require a server restart - actually anything in WEB-INF. Any changes to css/html will also require you to re-deploy in case you are deploying as a war. A reploy is not needed in case you are using an exploded war (which I guess you are)

> Server.xml and context.xml requires restart or not?

Changes in server.xml require a  restart. Changes in context.xml at least require a [re-deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828296/tomcat-7-avoid-automatic-restart-when-change-context-xml)

Comment: web.xml requires restart?

Comment: or a redploy, so I said anything in WEB-INF

Comment: how can I redeploy using command line, I mean which file should I run?

Comment: Use wget (also avaialble for windows). http://blog.denevell.org/tomcat7-manager-deploy-undeploy.html